# How to print row and column labels to output csv file

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, csv

I have an dataset of 1620 rows 7 columns. I want to keep every 5th row value starting from 1st row and delete the other rows, for my complete dataset. So I want to store 1st, 6th, 11th, 16th...so on rows  for full dataset in my csv file using python.

I have done this, and stored output to a csv file, but i am not getting row and column labels in my output csv. I want to get row and column labels in my output csv.

**Modification to this:**
I want to get the row labels as 1,2,3,4,5..so on instead of 1, 6, 11,16,21....

Dataset:

```
Serial,A,B,C,D,E,F
1,3.8,-5.9,-1.7,-1.4,8.3,-3.1
2,-5.4,-71.3,83.4,50.7,-1.3,88.4
3,3.0,5.3,1.4,5.7,6.6,2.3
4,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
6,-1.4,2.8,3.5,-6.7,-2.3,1.4
7,88.2,-0.1,-10.7,-36.2,88.1,-1.7
8,3.7,7.0,1.1,2.2,5.9,3.6
9,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
10,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
11,3.0,-1.6,-1.7,-4.2,7.8,-9.7
12,-7.1,-48.8,85.7,46.0,-2.8,-80.8
13,2.2,8.5,1.3,9.3,6.1,7.0
14,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
15,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
16,3.7,-6.2,-5.1,-2.5,0.0,-1.1
17,0.0,-60.3,88.8,45.1,0.0,90.0
18,2.9,9.3,3.9,8.3,6.9,8.6
19,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
20,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
21,3.7,-3.1,-8.3,-1.1,8.7,-3.3
```

[image: data]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#importing straintest dataset with pandas
dataset=pd.read_csv('ABC.csv')
dataset = dataset.set_index('Serial')

X =dataset.iloc[::5, :].values

np.savetxt('Output.csv', X, delimiter= ',')
print("::::\n",X)
```

Actual Output:

```
3.8,-5.9,-1.7,-1.4,8.3,-3.1
-1.4,2.8,3.5,-6.7,-2.3,1.4
3,-1.6,-1.7,-4.2,7.8,-9.7
3.7,-6.2,-5.1,-2.5,0,-1.1
3.7,-3.1,-8.3,-1.1,8.7,-3.3
```

[image: act]

Expected Output:

```
Serial,A,B,C,D,E,F
1,3.8,-5.9,-1.7,-1.4,8.3,-3.1
2,-1.4,2.8,3.5,-6.7,-2.3,1.4
3,3,-1.6,-1.7,-4.2,7.8,-9.7
4,3.7,-6.2,-5.1,-2.5,0,-1.1
5,3.7,-3.1,-8.3,-1.1,8.7,-3.3
```

[image: expct]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need columns names you can use pandas method [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
#remove .values
X = dataset.iloc[::5]
X.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

Or:

```
dataset=pd.read_csv('ABC.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[::5]
X.to_csv('Output.csv', index=False)
```

EDIT: You can create default index starting from `0`, if necessary starting from `1` add `rename`:

```
X = dataset.iloc[::5].reset_index(drop=True).rename(index = lambda x: x + 1)
X.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

Or:

```
dataset=pd.read_csv('ABC.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[::5].copy()
X['Serial'] = np.arange(1, len(X) + 1) 
X.to_csv('Output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Just a slight mod to the above, I want the row labels to be 1,2,3,4,5...so on..instead of 1,6,11,16,21...

Comment: The last code worked. Just could it be done without specifying the Label ```['Serial']```  As the labels might change every time, but the same code might work for other files as well.

Comment: @Axay - So is possible say need working with first column in DataFrame? Like `X.iloc[:, 0] = np.arange(1, len(X) + 1)` ?